# Create portal on JavaScript library create callback

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-portal

I have an external library (DataTable) which manipulates the DOM outside React, luckily the library offers some callback whenever an element is created (in this case a column).

At the moment I'm using this callback to overidde the default render behaviour and render inside the element a React Component:

```
// This is a method of the parent component
createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <SdrStatus sdr={rowData} details={false} tableRef={tableRef}/>,
        td
    );
},
```

Everything is fine a part that this SdrStatus component is not a child of the parent component (with all the cons context not share, ...)

I would like to connect this child component with the parent component using portal:

```
// This is a method of the parent component
createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
    ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <SdrStatus sdr={rowData} details={false} tableRef={tableRef}/>,
        td
    );
},
```

But in this case on the UI the results is the following:

[image]

Does anybody know which could be the issue here? Please consider that from DOM perspective td is a child of the container div for the parent component (maybe this is unexpected for createPortal)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell with the limited information, but the screenshot you have attached with the [object object] generally happens when react props seep into the DOM. Meaning, there is probably a mismatch of props you are provided to the component/table. Is the TD itself in React or is it managed outside of React? The answer would depended on that.

Comment: This is not an answer. When you have enough reputation, please post this as a comment.